# blur overlay for camera preview using tokbox

Tags: android, tokbox

I want to blur the camera preview in a video call. For a video call, I am using tokbox. But blur camera will be for 30 seconds of interval afterward normal camera preview will be seen. If anyone has achieved this then please help.

I have tried using Blurkit library but of no help. At last, I have changed some shader codes but tokbox allows custom renderer for one time only. How to change it after 30 seconds.
So far I have tried what is given in this

> https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/blob/master/Live-Photo-Capture/app/src/main/java/com/tokbox/android/tutorials/live_photo_capture/BasicCustomVideoRenderer.java

**UPDATE**

I am trying this with different fragment shaders. 
I am using 2 vertex shaders and 2 fragment shaders (one fragment and vertex for normal view and one fragment and vertex shader for blur view).

```
 private final String vertexShaderCode = "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;"
                + "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n"
                + "attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;\n"
                + "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" + "void main() {\n"
                + "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n"
                + "  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;\n" + "}\n";

        private final String fragmentShaderCode = "precision mediump float;\n"
                + "uniform sampler2D Ytex;\n"
                + "uniform sampler2D Utex,Vtex;\n"
                + "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n"
                + "void main(void) {\n"
                + "  float nx,ny,r,g,b,y,u,v;\n"
                + "  mediump vec4 txl,ux,vx;"
                + "  nx=vTextureCoord[0];\n"
                + "  ny=vTextureCoord[1];\n"
                + "  y=texture2D(Ytex,vec2(nx,ny)).r;\n"
                + "  u=texture2D(Utex,vec2(nx,ny)).r;\n"
                + "  v=texture2D(Vtex,vec2(nx,ny)).r;\n"

                //+ "  y=1.0-1.1643*(y-0.0625);\n" // Invert effect
                + "  y=1.1643*(y-0.0625);\n" // Normal renderer

                + "  u=u-0.5;\n" + "  v=v-0.5;\n" + "  r=y+1.5958*v;\n"
                + "  g=y-0.39173*u-0.81290*v;\n" + "  b=y+2.017*u;\n"
                + "  gl_FragColor=vec4(r,g,b,1.0);\n" + "}\n";

        public static final String vertexShaderCode1 = "" +
                "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
                "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +

                "const int GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES = 9;\n" +

                "uniform vec2 singleStepOffset;\n" +

                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "varying vec2 blurCoordinates[GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES];\n" +

                "void main()\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "   gl_Position = aPosition;\n" +
                "   vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord.xy;\n" +

                "   int multiplier = 0;\n" +
                "   vec2 blurStep;\n" +

                "   for (int i = 0; i < GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES; i++)\n" +
                "   {\n" +
                "       multiplier = (i - ((GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES - 1) / 2));\n" +

                "       blurStep = float(multiplier) * singleStepOffset;\n" +
                "       blurCoordinates[i] = aTextureCoord.xy + blurStep;\n" +
                "   }\n" +
                "}";

        public static final String fragmentShaderCode1 = "" +
                "uniform sampler2D Ytex;\n" +

                " const lowp int GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES = 9;\n" +

                " varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;\n" +
                " varying highp vec2 blurCoordinates[GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES];\n" +

                " uniform mediump float distanceNormalizationFactor;\n" +

                " void main()\n" +
                " {\n" +
                "     lowp vec4 centralColor;\n" +
                "     lowp float gaussianWeightTotal;\n" +
                "     lowp vec4 sum;\n" +
                "     lowp vec4 sampleColor;\n" +
                "     lowp float distanceFromCentralColor;\n" +
                "     lowp float gaussianWeight;\n" +
                "     \n" +
                "     centralColor = texture2D(Ytex, blurCoordinates[4]);\n" +
                "     gaussianWeightTotal = 0.18;\n" +
                "     sum = centralColor * 0.18;\n" +
                "     \n" +
                "     sampleColor = texture2D(Ytex, blurCoordinates[0]);\n" +
                "     distanceFromCentralColor = min(distance(centralColor, sampleColor) * distanceNormalizationFactor, 1.0);\n" +
                "     gaussianWeight = 0.05 * (1.0 - distanceFromCentralColor);\n" +
                "     gaussianWeightTotal += gaussianWeight;\n" +
                "     sum += sampleColor * gaussianWeight;\n" +

                "     sampleColor = texture2D(Ytex, blurCoordinates[8]);\n" +
                "     distanceFromCentralColor = min(distance(centralColor, sampleColor) * distanceNormalizationFactor, 1.0);\n" +
                "     gaussianWeight = 0.05 * (1.0 - distanceFromCentralColor);\n" +
                "     gaussianWeightTotal += gaussianWeight;\n" +
                "     sum += sampleColor * gaussianWeight;\n" +
                "     gl_FragColor = sum / gaussianWeightTotal;\n" +
                " }";
```

I want to switch between 2 fragment shaders on the click of a button. I have tried something like this
In OnDrawFrame()

```
  int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);

                int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

                mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram(); 
                GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader); 
                GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); 
                GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

                GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
```

But it is not working. So my question is how can I switch between 2 different fragment shaders.

Comment: Just ignore the comment if it is so dumb :-) . How About placing the surfaceview and a View (with alpha color) together inside a RelativeLayout and after 30 seconds set the visibility of the View to GONE.